# Put each variable into one string if it doesn't exceed x characters

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a few variables set, example:

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$tag1 = '#lorem1';
$tag2 = '#lorem2';
$tag3 = '#lorem3';
$tag4 = '#lorem4';
$tag5 = '#lorem5';
```

I want to put them all together into a string. Something like this:

```
$final = $url .' '. $tag1 .' '. $tag2...
```

However, if the `$final` string will exceed 140 characters, then do not add variable.

So for example, if `$final` string is 137 characters, then do not add `$tag5` into joined variable string because its value will make it exceed 140 characters.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to code a simple loop like this:

```
$str = '';
foreach($parts as $part)
{
    if(strlen($str.$part) >= 140)
    {
        break;
    }
    $str .= $part;
}
return $str;
```

This is pretty much the only way to do this IMO.

Comment: You'll have to put your "tags" into an array for this to work

Comment: To confirm, I need to put all variables in an array named $parts in order for this to work?

Comment: Very nice, works great. I will accept in one moment.

Answer (score 0):

LET suppose u made $array_name_str which store all the strings u mentioned.

```
$nb_input = 0;
$final_str = '';

foreach($array_name_str ad $row)
{
    $length_curr_str = strlen($row);
    if( $length_curr_str > (140 - $nb_input))
        break;

    // We add the curr string
    $final_str .= $row;
    $final_str .= " ";

    // Updating size of output str
    $nb_input += $length_curr_str;
}
return $final_str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here with limit option that could be used anytime by any condition;

```
function to_tag(array $tags, $limit = 140) {
    $str = '';
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $str .= ' '. trim($tag);
        if (strlen($str) > $limit) {
            $str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, ' '));
            break;
        }
    }

    return trim($str);
}

print_r(to_tag(['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3'], 10)); // foo1 foo2
```